# Jump to next line after writing a word in a file

Tags: javascript, fs, writefile

```
user_bw = message.content;
fs.writeFile("badwordlog.txt", user_bw, (err) => {
  if (err)
    console.log(err);
  else {
    console.log("badwordlog edited !");
       
  }
});
```

I need to store all the badwords in a file . How to print the next word in the next line? I tried `\n` but it was not working.

Comment: Hi ! On which server platform ? Unix-like, Windows ? In the second case, you could try with `\r\n` ?

Answer (score 2):

The reason for this is that writeFile will replace the whole file. You can pass in a option flag which tells it to append new text to it.
You may try:

```
user_bw = message.content;
fs.writeFile("badwordlog.txt", user_bw, { flag: "a+" }, (err) => {
  if (err)
    console.log(err);
  else {
    console.log("badwordlog edited !");
       
  }
});
```

Comment: You must be right, I have (again) been caught by the `it was not working` ;)